How to use built-in OpenVPN client on ASUS RT-AC66U router?
I have a Linux with OpenVPN server installed and when I connect to it from my PC over OpenVPN client everything works just fine. So, all parts are in place.
Now I tried to use built-in OpenVPN client on ASUS RT-AC66U router following the How to set up VPN Client in ASUS router manual.
Just to have the same terms in the question below:

All web sites - any site on the web
Restricted sites - sites visible from my network (via my provider) without VPN.
Blocked sites - sites not visible from my network, but visible via VPN from another provider.

I get connected and got the tick icon in ASUS router GUI, but my devices don’t see any blocked sites; still can see restricted sites, so everything works as before turning on router OpenVPN client.
I refreshed all network settings on PC (Windows 10) with:
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
route /f

and after that I stopped to see all web sites until I turned OpenVPN Client on router off and restarted PC.
Have a missed something? What should be done to get access like I have with OpenVPN client?
Update
Based on the comments I conducted the following steps.
Before starting I called the https://www.whatsmyip.org/ and get the address (188.xxx.yyy.zzz).
After activating the VPN Client on the router I called the https://www.whatsmyip.org/ again and got the same address (188.xxx.yyy.zzz).
I ran the network refreshing script quoted above and PC has stopped to see any internet resources, including the https://www.whatsmyip.org/ (no ping, to tracert work, as well).
I restarted the PC, the same thing; no access to any interned site.
I turned off the VPN Client on the router and now things get back to the start.
Please note, that router manual doesn't suggest any additional steps to get VPN working, no changes in DNS addresses, routes, etc.
ovpn file
As requested in comments here is the ovpn file (with xxx.yyy.zzz.www is the address of the server and "..." are the keys/certificates).
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.yyy.zzz.www 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>...</ca>
<cert>...</cert>
<key>...</key>
<tls-crypt>...</tls-crypt>


Screenshots are not helpful

@Ramhound, sorry?

What DO your devices see through the VPN? Are they connecting, but outside the VPN? Are they NOT connecting? What IS happening?

Typo. Screenshots of the interface, your settings, etc would be helpful. I assume you can’t provide the server logs on the router.

@music2myear, actually when I start OpenVPN client on the router, nothing changes for the devices. They still see the restricted sites and don't see blocked sites. Like nothing changed. Should I check something with ping/tracert, etc.? I updated the comment with the actions I took and some introduced terms to be clear.

@Ramhound, I would avoid providing to much security-related details, I hope you understand this. What information exactly (routing, mapping, DNS configuration, subnet masks) should help? Or, what is the starting point to look into? If VPN Client works fine, where could be the disconnect? What kind of debugging (ping, tracert, nslookup, etc.) could help? Where to start from?

How are the sites being blocked over the VPN? DNS, or some other method? If DNS, there are many ways around this, and you'd have to clear DNS cache or wait for it to expire before the filtering would apply.

@music2myear, what is the best way to check this? Run nslookup or something else?

@DamirTenishev have you at least checked whether the tunnel is used at all with one of those whatsmyip websites/services first?

I presume you have applied some sort of controls over the VPN, so a test would be whether those controls work. Also, like Tom Yan mentions, a WhatIsMyIP service will allow you to see whether public sites see your ISP IP or your VPN tunnel IP.

@TomYan, I've checked with  https://www.whatsmyip.org/. When VPN Client started, the address is the same; when I reset network on PC, it stops seeing web at all. Please see more details in the Update section in the updated question.

@music2myear, please see the results of the attempt in the Update section in the updated question.

@DamirTenishev If the public IP (as seen by the outside) does not change, then it probably means that somehow your router's effective default route is not updated. Maybe it's time for you to post ovpn file you imported to your router (make sure you redact the sensitive stuff before you submit. Edit is not going to make them actually go away, so be careful).

@TomYan, will do. One question on the "Edit is not going to make them actually go away"? What do you mean with "edit" here? The ovpn is the plain text file and am going to copy/paste most of the info except IP addresses and certificates. If I remove them directly from the text by edit in Nodepad++, in which way "Edit is not going to make them actually go away"? Do you mean another type of edit in some OpenVPN editor?

@DamirTenishev before you submit obviously I mean the edit on the site. Every revision is "logged" like when you are working with a git repo: https://superuser.com/posts/1849564/revisions

@TomYan, thank you now I got that you meant the copying and editing on the site. The ovpn file content has been provided. Could you please take a look?

@DamirTenishev See if adding redirect-gateway def1 to it makes a difference. If it doesn't, try redirect-gateway instead.

@TomYan, just to make sure that nothing is missed; did you really mean a pure redirect-gateway instead? Anyway, tried both options directly and with running network reset script above; nothing has changed. The same behavior.
